# How do split columns of csv file after importing in jupetyr notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have imported the csv file onto jupetyr notebook, but i am unable to visualize properly

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: date,time,speedb,PWGa,PWGb,CBIN,CBB,PCVBF,CBRTIN,CBDVH,CBDVH,CBHPP,CBHPP,CBBF,CBDE,CBRE
0  07.02.2020,07:05:33:661,1148,0.9,0.9,81.3,80.8...
1  07.02.2020,07:05:36:686,1242,0.6,0.6,81.3,81,5...
2  07.02.2020,07:05:39:700,651,2.5,2.5,81.3,80.9,...
3  07.02.2020,07:05:42:724,920,3.4,3.4,81.2,81,54...
4  07.02.2020,07:05:45:739,1147,3.7,3.7,81.2,81,5...
5  07.02.2020,07:05:48:763,1081,2.9,2.9,81.1,81,5...
6  07.02.2020,07:05:51:777,1021,3.3,3.3,81.1,81.1...

Comment: csv file is importing into jupetyr,but its not splitted by columns

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random

hot=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\dhr3ban\Desktop\denga.csv',sep=';',index_col=0)

type(hot)

Comment: above is my import csv command

Comment: the separator looks like `,` comma and you are using `sep=';'`, try removing that argument and let pandas infer it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas library and read your data as a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv('\filepath')
```

Then you visualize your columns as:

```
dataframe.columns
```

or you can visualize a snapshot of your data like this:

```
dataframe.head()
```

or perhaps access a column value by referencing it like this: dataframe['column_name'].

Read a quick tutorial here: https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/python-pandas-cheat-sheet